# New window popup is blank in chrome, but works in IE and firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Here is my code.

```
<form name = "SearchForm" id = "SearchForm" 
    method = "post" 
    onSubmit =
        "<%if(contextType.equals("EXAM")){%>
             window.open('', 'searchResults',
                         'width = 615, height = 515,
                          resizable = yes, scrollbars = yes');
         <%}%>
         doSearch('resultsdiv',1);
         return false;"
>
```

New window opens in chrome without search results, but opens in Firefox and IE with search results.

Comment: Is your popup blocker on?

Comment: popup opens ..But the popup is blank in chrome.But in firefox it has some results

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name = "SearchForm" id = "SearchForm" method = "get" target=searchResults onSubmit="window.open('', 'searchResults', 'width = 615, height = 515, resizable = yes, scrollbars = yes'); return true;">
<input type="text" name="foo" size="15" value="Hello World!">
<input type="Submit" value="Try">
</form>
<script>
var x=self.location.href.split('=');
if(x.length==2){
document.write('<h3>You have successfully popped up a search for: '+unescape(x[1].replace(/\+/gi,' ')).replace(/\</gi,'&lt;'));

};
</script>
```

Sample here: (dead link)
Added: `target=searchResults`, changed return to `true`.

I also changed post to get (so that you can see it transferred the query; POST would work fine) and stripped your specific things, but it works now. Tested in Chrome and FF, it's good.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing similar issue. The problem was because of submit button which does autopostback once and I had attached a javascript function on the same button , which made postback twice. To resolve this I disabled the autopostback of submit button, just set the the property "AutoPostBack" of button to "False" and it worked.